# Django How to display 2 objects in one list by subscript

Tags: django, django-templates

After running a query on two tables not related by primary key, I was able to 'join' the resultant objects into a list containing 2 different objects. I used the list because the objects are related but I have no other way of relating them other than adding them both to a list once a certain condition was true. I am now trying to display them in the html as they have different fields and I'd like to choose the ones to display.

I initially tried something like this:

```
{% for record in results %}
{{ record[0].field_name }}
{{ record[1].field_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I've also tried some of the filters like below with no luck.

`{{ record |first|attr('field_name') }}`

Please advise on how I can use these 2 objects and display the relevant fields from both.

Comment: `record.0.field_name` and `record.1.field_name` should work.

Comment: Thanks, that's it!!!